# Typescript: polymorphism by kind

Tags: typescript

Yesterday I listened to a podcast that said typescript has a feature that I'm unable to find. It works like this:

```
const funct = (): (Type1 | Type2) {//...}
```

Here we have a function that returns a union type.  The podcast said there is a way of specifying a field in Type1/2 that will be used to differentiate which type I'm working with. For example, I could have a string in both types called `differentiator` and make sure that each type has a unique value. Then, when I call this function, I can check which differentiator the result has, and act appropriately.

The discussion used the keyword `kind` or `kindof`.  When I searched for this feature, this result keeps showing up: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html But that article doesn't mention the concept of `kind` . It gives other ways of differentiating union types, but nothing to do with "Kind." I think the word may be too common for it to be easy to Google for this feature.

The question is this:

1. Assuming this feature exists, what's it called?
2. How do I use this feature? I'd like to see how to define the union type and how to differentiate the union type.

Comment: It's called [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).  Not sure if this needs its own answer?

Comment: @jcalz that looks like it to me